# redirecting with Better WP Security plugin for Wordpress

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, nginx

I am using Wordpress along with another application server (with Nginx in front).  The application server communicates with an Angular app on the front end.  When a certain URL is accessed on the broswer (while HTML5 mode is enabled i.e. no hash sign in the URL), instead of the correct route being hit on the application server, the request is handled by Wordpress instead (which is not the intended behavior).  For instance, if the url is http://www.test.com/signup, instead of the regular signup route being picked (on the back end application server, the signup is being handled by Wordpress - Nginx does not have a rule for this route and the route hits the rule in Nginx for Wordpress).  I am trying to redirect the url so that instead of http://www.test.com/signup pointing to wordpress signup, it takes me to the application signup instead.  I believe I can achieve this via Nginx but I have been asked not to.  Is Better WP Security the best tool to achieve this objective?  I could not figure out where to reroute traffic from WP-Traffic - any insight into this matter will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there something wrong, and you loo for the routing error, or is all as expected, and you just look for a way to redirect?

Comment: I can redirect with nginx etc - nginx is forwarding part of the traffic to wordpress which is handling the url mentioned in the question /(which is not something I am looking for).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Simple 301 Redirect plugin to redirect traffic (could have used Nginx as well).  With Simple 301 Redirect plugin, you can add a link and the destination to which it needs to redirect to using the plugin->settings option.